# How can I call the function of methods in function of mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my Vue mounted code, I am calling a function test via this.getFile(file). This works fine as intended.

When however I am calling this.display(text) from the function of mounted, I am getting an error

> this.display is not a function

I understand that this is because the this there is now pointing to the their parent. What I do not understand is what I should use there instead. Removing the this also gives an error.

I have the following Vue code

```
      mounted() {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = evt => {
          const text = evt.target.result
          this.display(text)
        };
      },
      methods: {
        display(text){
          console.log('this is test', text)
        }
      }
```

Comment: Use `bind()` to make the `this` available to inner function in mounted, or make use of arrow function.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed my post simply, would you like to attach the comment in my code?